# Why does this work in safari but not firefox?

Tags: html, html5-audio

The following code does not automatically begin playing an mp3 in Firefox, but it does in safari and chrome. Is this a plugin issue? How do I make this work? I'm sorry for the simple question, I do feel like I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure this out.

```
 <html>
        <body>
         <audio src="songs/01.mp3"  
                autoplay>  
           Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.  
         </audio>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mozilla foundation doesn't like mp3s very much:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/audio

> Note: Currently, Gecko supports only Vorbis, in Ogg containers, as well as WAV format.  Also, the server must serve the file using the correct MIME type in order for Gecko to play it correctly.

You can specify multiple sources in different formats if you want to be cross-browser compatible. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Source

Oh, you thought HTML5 got rid of cross-browser compatibility issues? Sorry to disappoint. ;)

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html#what-works